# How to disable the CSRF function in Impresspages forms?

Tags: csrf, impresspages

I wish to know how to disable the CSRF function in Impresspages forms. I'm building a custom made form which do not use the form builder of Impresspages but on form submit, I get the following error:

{"status":"error","errors":{"securityToken":"Possible CSRF attack...

Can someone tell me where to add the CSRF disable function.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the form where you have to turn it off. Cross site request forgery check is related to controllers.

ImpressPages require a securityToken variable if you POST data to the controller. All you have to do is to add a hidden field with name 'securityToken' and value:

PHP: ipSecurityToken()
or
JavaScript: ip.securityToken

You can skip all of that by posting to PublicController.php but you will likely have a code which has CSRF hole.

All about securityToken and PublicController which has no CSRF check can be found here
 http://www.impresspages.org/docs/controller